# Two bootstrap typeaheads on same page with two different source functions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'd like two different text inputs to have typeahead, each with a different source function. For the sake of example, one gets first_names and the other last_names.

Here's how it looks and it's not working:

```
$('#first_name').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        $.get('/users/typeahead-first-name', { term: query }, function (data) {
            return process(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    }
});

$('#last_name').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        $.get('/users/typeahead-last-name', { term: query }, function (data) {
            return process(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    }
});
```

The first typeahead works fine. However, the 2nd one, when I start typing and the options start to appear, then I click an option, the dropdown just closes and no value is inserted into the input field.

Anybody's got any idea how to get it to work?

Comment: What doesn't work? ANy errors logged in the browser console?

Comment: Have you checked the response of the Ajax call with a web inspector (F12) ?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work: both typeaheads load data from the server correctly per each input. However, selecting the desired row from the suggested result and placing it's value inside the input field works ONLY for the first one.

Comment: Try reproducing the bug with minimal code, because it works fine there (no `JSON.parse` is part of the jsfiddle tweaks): http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/KKQsK/

Comment: @Sherbrow it didn't. I mean, it did once, but I tried many times and in the majority of the times it acted just the same as in my own experience. I believe the fact that it DID work once, means there's something async going on that once in a lucky time syncs right (but most of the time it doesn't)

Comment: @shaharsol Then the first step would be to do a proper ajax handling (error cases, etc) and store requests to cancel them if a new one come before the last one has ended - on a per-typeahead basis of course

Answer (score 4):

This may be a little late to help you, but I just had the same problem in my own app.  The solution was to add "name" attributes, like this:

```
$('#first_name').typeahead({
    name: 'first_name',
    source: function (query, process) {
        $.get('/users/typeahead-first-name', { term: query }, function (data) {
            return process(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    }
});

$('#last_name').typeahead({
    name: 'last_name',
    source: function (query, process) {
        $.get('/users/typeahead-last-name', { term: query }, function (data) {
            return process(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    }
});
```

It didn't matter what I called them in my code, as long as they were different.  It makes some sense too, since typeahead keeps a cache of responses.  (Although I would have thought they would have just tied the cache to the instance you're binding it to, but...)

Comment: Cheers to the late responses!  +1